# mod_rewrite - RewriteRule - redirecting to index not showing css,images,etc

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRules in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+)/ index.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/
```

I plan to redirect any directory request back to index.php, keeping the URI information for processing. These rules allow me to do that, but my style sheet and images are not showing up once the index loads. My stylesheet is included as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/chat.css" />
```

Images are included in a similar fashion. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path to you css and images? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://websitename.com/css/chat.css" />` & `<img src='http://websitename.com/imgs/image.jpg' />`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. I just realized that EVERY request is being redirected to index.php including the one requesting the style sheet. I guess what I have to do is make a condition to only redirect if not requesting a particular file?

Comment: A request for an image or CSS file is still a request to your webserver and are still subject to these rules. I would suggest adding rewrite conditions to ignore files or directories or add rules to allow CSS/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules should use conditions to exclude real files or directories.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+)/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm :). Thanks again everyone for your help! For anyone that may come across this in the future, you have to do what Peter said to make the images, css, and scripts show across all directories.